# Magento Form in 2 columns

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have 2 forms on one page in the admin of Magento
I would like them side by side, one is informational only and the other is editable

I have been playing with the layout.xml reference name="left" and "right" however I have been unsuccessful, can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this by using a wrapper
in the layout.xml

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="block" name="name"/>
</reference>
```

template file

```
<div id="main-content-area">
    <div id="right-col" style="width:49%;display: inline;float:left;">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('blockname')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="left-col" style="width:49%;display: inline;float:right;margin-top:-1px;">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('blockname')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```